# How to modify default sql after authorization on Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If you look through the picture you can see on my Laravel 5 project I have successfully authorized and my Laravel DebugBar shows default sql at below:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = 2 Limit 1
```

I am looking for the way to modify this sql after successfully authorization, like this:

```
SELECT
  u.*, c.companyName
FROM
  users u
LEFT JOIN companies c
  ON c.id = u.companyId
WHERE
  u.id = ?
  LIMIT 1
```

[image]

Comment: Is that query comming form the the Laravel Auth system? Meaning that you are using `Auth::user` to get the authenticated user details.

Comment: @Bogdan, Yes this query is coming from the Laravel Auth system. So I want to display the company name using this: `Auth::user()->companyName`

Comment: Have you set up the relationship ?

Comment: @lagbox No. I have built tables (`users`, `companies`) using migrations. I am new on Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here. Either extend the Authentication driver and modify the `retrieveById` method to return your company name along with the user details, or create a relationship with the `Company` model, which I'm guessing is **one-to-many**, a company can have many users, while a user can belong to one company. I'd pick the latter which would make more sense in this case.

You can create the `Company` model by running:

```sh
php artisan make:model Company
```

Then you can add this to the `User` model that comes with the authentication system:

```php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'companyId');
}
```

Now you can do the following to access company details for your authenticated user:

```php
Auth::user()->company->companyName;
```

That's because when you call `Auth::user()->company` you get an instance of the `Company` that is attached to the user.

You can read more on Eloquent [Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) and [Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) in the Laravel Documentation.

Comment: thank you very much. I chose second option and this is exactly nice and easy method to solve the problem. I didn't know about Eloquent ORM

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you're new to Laravel, I suggest you read the [Quickstart Help Section](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart), and if you have time, the entire documentation, because it can give you a great sense of what the framework can offer.

Comment: is it possible to merge this 2 queries using left join?

Comment: Unfortunatelly in this case no, because the initial query is built by the authentication system, which means you don't have access to it unless you extend the authentication driver (which was the first option I suggested). But if this is a performance concern, I wouldn't be too worried about one simple extra query per request, because from my experience this is not where bottlenecks happen, so I suggest you optimize only if/when needed.